# How can I translate the Technical Settings Infos from SAP into an ID?

Tags: sap-gui

I am currently working on SAP Scripting with Python and I would like to ask you for an alternative way of getting the ID of an object.

I saw that the scripting tracker from Stefan Schnell would be perfect for this but unfortunately, I am working on my company-notebook on this topic (for bachelor-thesis) and Windows Defender is blocking the .exe

Since it would be quite hard to get my admin to amend my permissions, I thought maybe it is possible to get the ID from the information in "technical settings" from SAP itself.

[image]

According to an old quora-post this should be possible (https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-obtain-SAP-ID-Objects-to-write-SAP-Scripts-when-SAP-Script-Recording-is-disabled-in-my-company-Is-there-a-software-to-read-buttons-tabs-and-fields-names-IDs)
what I am having trouble with, is how to "translate" this information properly to make python understand it. According to the quora post, I have tried things like this:

`session.FindById('wnd[0]/usr/SAPLMEGUI:1211/EMATN/MEPO1211-EMATN').text = "test"`

which unfortunately did not work.

Comment: I have found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541753/how-to-get-the-idobject-with-attribute-in-sap-using-automation-anywhere-with-dll/56561036#56561036 Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the IDObject with Attribute in SAP using Automation Anywhere with DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541753/how-to-get-the-idobject-with-attribute-in-sap-using-automation-anywhere-with-dll)